# MySQL Connection Limit Advice

Tags: mysql

I've hit a problem with my MySQL queries and was hoping someone could offer some help/advice.

I'm developing a PHP-based system which combines quite a lot of data in different tabs on one page (tab1 = profile, tab2 = address, tab3 = payments etc.) and as a result, one page can have up to 34/40 MySQL queries pulling from different tables or with different criteria.

The page load became really slow and I asked my web host if they knew what was wrong and they advised it's because of slow MySQL queries (some over 2 seconds). They also said that my MySQL user is only allowed 15 connections at a time.

If my page has 40 queries and only 15 connections are allowed at a time, does this mean they effectively queue and wait for one to complete? If this was the case then I can understand why the page is taking a while to load but i'm not sure of the solution. Is 15 MySQL queries considered a lot or is this quite a tight restriction by my host (HostMonster)?

Also, if there were 15 users accessing the system at the same time, would this 15 connections be split between each of them or is it 15 connections per user logged into the site? I assume they mean per database user but all people who access the system will be using the same database user so it seems impossible to create a system in which several users can access at one?

The whole connections thing has confused me a little.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If a PHP page contains 40 queries, these queries will be executed serially, i.e. the next query will only be issued when the previous one has returned. 15 connections means 15 page requests with queries can (in theory) be executed at the same time. As soon as a page request has been handled by PHP, it releases its connection, so it becomes free for the next page request.
I think, 15 connections is enough for a small web application for a handful of users, but is clearly not enough for a medium to big application with hundreds to thousands of users.

Comment: See if you can do some query optimisation with `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and sub-selects. 40 queries per page is intense. Also, have a look into integrating memcached for result sets that won't always be unique or can be shared among users; it will allow you to offload some of the database requests.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have one connection per page. Put the queries into sequence
2. Optimize those queries - see explain and use indexes
3. Perhaps combine queries to reduce the through put.

BTW 10+ queries per page is excessive IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If having max connect error problem then use this command from command line

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts  -uuser -p'password'
```

this will flush hosts that MySQL has recorded and will build the list again. In the newer version of MYSQL 5.6 you get more information on this but not on previous version.

You can set the following

```
max_connect_errors 10000
```

to avoid the message to appear again.

15 queries or connection is not a problem at all, in busy databases we have seen thousand connections and tens of thousands of queries per second.